# Runtime Error attempt to index local 'fay' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a simple menu. My program compiles fine on windows in the Corona emulator however when I build the program for android it receives the "Runtime Error attempt to index local 'example1' (a nil value). Does anyone know how to help me out? it would be much appreciated!! 
Here is the updated code

```
module (...,package.seeall)

  function new()

    local menuGroup = display.newGroup()

    local background = display.newImage("graphics/background3.png")


    local example1 = display.newImage("graphics/Example1.png")
    example1.x = 720
    example1.y = 150
    example1.scene = "example1"

    local example2 = display.newImage("graphics/Example2.png")
    example2.x = 720
    example2.y = 450
    example2.scene = "example2"

    local example3 = display.newImage("graphics/Example3.png")
    example3.x = 720
    example3.y = 750
    example3.scene = "example3"

    local example4 = display.newImage("graphics/Example4.png")
    example4.x = 720
    example4.y = 1050
    example4.scene = "example4"

    menuGroup:insert(background)
    menuGroup:insert(example1)
    menuGroup:insert(example2)
    menuGroup:insert(example3)
    menuGroup:insert(example4)

    example1:addEventListener("touch", changeScene)
    example2:addEventListener("touch", changeScene)
    example3:addEventListener("touch", changeScene)
    example4:addEventListener("touch", changeScene)

    return menuGroup
end
```

Comment: Where does it indicate the error is coming from? (The `= {}` bit of the `local fay` line is unnecessary since you assign the result from `display.newImage` to `fay` directly after that.)

Comment: `display.newImage("graphics/Example1.png")` is likely returning `nil`. Also  the assignments `tey = {}` and `fay = {}` are redundant, since you immediately reassign them on the next lines.

Comment: Ill grab it right now

Comment: I updated my code to my most recent, the error on my phone is "menu.lua:16:attempt to index local 'example1' (a nil value)

Comment: Why would display.newImage("graphics/Example1.png") bereturning nil?

Comment: make sure the path is correct and the name is with the right casing ("Example1" vs "example1"). This error happened to me before when I had something like: display.newImage("**/**graphics/Example1.png") instead of display.newImage("graphics/Example1.png") - it worked in the simulator but not on my device. Also check that you are not removing this image when building (in build.settings, under "excludeFiles")